# Can I force the loading order of javascripts in the Rails 3.2 Asset Pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have some javascripts that I have copied into:

```
app/assets/javascripts
```

Mostly jQuery plugins. Some of them I need to load in a certain order. I'm in the process of trying to enable back-button support in my Ajax application.

How can I impose a load order on tree items not explicitly listed in my `application.js` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery plugins should go in `lib/assets/javascripts` or `vendor/assets/javascripts`.

Then in your application.js manifest, simply include them in whatever order you want :

```
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.first_plugin
//= require jquery.first_plugin
```

The `require_tree` will not load what is inside `lib` and `vendor` folders